# How to keep user logged-in in Ionic app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I am developing an app with Ionic Framework and I did a test on Android so far it works well except after a few minutes of inactivity, the app asks the user to log back in with credentials.

I would like that the user NEVER has to log back in with a "remember me" function maybe ?

How to proceed ?

Here is my controller :

```
.controller('loginController',['$scope', '$firebaseArray', 'CONFIG', '$document', '$state', function($scope, $firebaseArray, CONFIG, $document, $state) {
  // Perform the login action when the user submits the login form
  $scope.doLogin = function(userLogin) {
        if($document[0].getElementById("user_name").value != "" && $document[0].getElementById("user_pass").value != ""){
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(userLogin.username, userLogin.password).then(function() {
                      $state.go("tab.favorites");

        }, function(error) {
          // An error happened.
          var errorCode = error.code;
          var errorMessage = error.message;

          if (errorCode === 'auth/invalid-email') {
             alert('Enter a valid email.');
             return false;
          }else if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {
             alert('Incorrect password.');
             return false;
          }else if (errorCode === 'auth/argument-error') {
             alert('Password must be string.');
             return false;
          }else if (errorCode === 'auth/user-not-found') {
             alert('No such user found.');
             return false;
          }else if (errorCode === 'auth/too-many-requests') {
             alert('Too many failed login attempts, please try after sometime.');
             return false;
          }else if (errorCode === 'auth/network-request-failed') {
             alert('Request timed out, please try again.');
             return false;
          }else {
             alert(errorMessage);
             return false;
          }
        });
    }else{
        alert('Please enter email and password');
        return false;
    }//end check client username password
  };// end $scope.doLogin()
}])
```

Comment: Nothing you have here illuminates what would cause the user to log in multiple times. This is the code that performs the authentication, not the code that invokes it, and therefore not the source of the repeated calls. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hello, there is no multiple calls, it just happens when the user let the app in the background for like 20 minutes, then it is like the app rebooted and needs the user to authenticate again.

Comment: Hey FrenchyNYC, the Firebase auth state in an ionic/cordova app environment persists in localStorage. If that is cleared, then the state will be cleared and the user is asked to sign in again.